# Google Sheets: Count all rows after matching two criteria on two cells

Tags: google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

So I have a spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1je5poDRF2dmi8Zi7ZksVJrDNmsr-7lxn50mJF0Dyp_g/edit?usp=sharing), that contains all call data from my call center. We want to get totals of all the connected calls, missed calls, etc.., broken down into each month. I've managed to Google my way to creating a formula that adds up all the calls in the Month of January, and all calls that are tagged as "call connected."

Get all for a Month (correctly pulls all 15,187 rows that contain a date in January in the text)

```html
=counta(arrayformula(iferror(search("1/**/2018",Adherence!D:D))))
```

Get all that are Call connected - 6 month period (Correctly pulls all 66048 connected calls over the past 6 months)

```html
=counta(arrayformula(iferror(search("Call connected",Adherence!G:G))))
```

Can I use these formulas together to pull all the calls that took place in January AND are tagged with "Call connected" (66048)?

I thought I could use this formula:

```html
=ArrayFormula(counta(FILTER(Adherence!G:G,Adherence!G:G="Call connected"))+counta(filter(Adherence!D:D,Adherence!D:D="1/**/2018")))
```

But I instead get all of the calls with the tag "Call connected" again. What am I missing?

Please note I've tried Googling and even G-suite support before they directed me here. They seem to be saving a lot of money by shoveling their subscriber's issues into community forums instead of trying to be helpful ;-)

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable sharing on your sheet, but without that, I believe the problem is with the `+`.

Instead of `=ArrayFormula(counta(FILTER(Adherence!G:G,Adherence!G:G="Call connected"))+counta(filter(Adherence!D:D,Adherence!D:D="1/**/2018")))`,

try `=ArrayFormula(AND(counta(FILTER(Adherence!G:G,Adherence!G:G="Call connected")),counta(filter(Adherence!D:D,Adherence!D:D="1/**/2018"))))`.  I had similar issues with a compound formula, and switching to the `AND/,` mode fixed it for me.  Hopefully that should fix it for you.

Answer (score -1):

Sry, I had sensitive data on it beforehand, probably should have made a fresh sheet.

After further research and head scratching, I came up with this:

```html
=COUNTA(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(Adherence!$D:$G,"select D where D like '%1/__/2018' AND G contains 'Call connected'")))-1
```

It counts every item in the Array that comes back from querying every cell in column D that matches any date in January (I prefaced with % as a wildcard, as the date was prefaced with MON, TUE, WED, etc) and the cell in column G contains a special tag word.

I subtract the result by 1 because the results also include the header of the column, for some reason. Now I am getting accurate results.

Feel free to change up the columns tags for your needs, this is really just a formula for searching text in two places. May come in handy for somebody else.

Below were screenshots of the spreadsheet if it helps anyone through a similar problem

[image: Sheet 1 Illustrated what I was trying to do]

[image: Example of the Call Data I was working through]